# Leakcanary crashes with Google's Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, leakcanary

When processing a leak, I get a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist.` inside my `Application.onCreate`. From what I understand, this happens because LeakCanary creates my application class without all the Google Play Services stuff and Firebase cannot initialize successfully. Any ideas how to fix this?

Edit: 
I'm using `leakcanary-android:1.4-beta2` and this happens after dumping the heap.

Comment: Are you using Firebase Crash Reporting?

Comment: No, I call `FirebaseAuth.getInstance()`. Should've probabaly mentioned that.

Comment: Take a look here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=vi&fromgroups&nomobile=true#!topic/firebase-talk/ZIhO6Wwe1oM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found a workaround. Instead of using the Google Play Services plugin and `google-services.json` you can configure and initialize Firebase yourself in `Application.onCreate` or wherever.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
protected FirebaseApp proviceFirebaseApp(Application application) {
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApplicationId(application.getPackageName())
            .setDatabaseUrl(BuildConfig.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL)
            .setApiKey(BuildConfig.FIREBASE_API_KEY)
            .build();
    return FirebaseApp.initializeApp(application, options);
}
```

Finding the keys was a bit of a mystery. Inside `google-services.json` you'll need the database url, which is `project_info.firebase_url`. If you have more than one application using the Firebase repo, there will be multiple `client` objects here.

If you're using Google Sign In, the oauth id is inside `client[app].oauth_client[1].client_id`. You can figure out your `client` according to the package name and the `oauth_client` was the second object that looked like this:

```
{
  "client_id": "asfagasdgdas",
  "client_type": 3
}
```

The api key is `client[app].api_key`, again find the client based on your package.

Forgive the pseudo-json.

The structure might change later, this was written for Play Services version 9.0.1.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you could leave the google play services plugin configuration as suggested by the documentation.

Disable FirebaseInitProvider by adding this to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider
    android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
    android:enabled="false" />
```

And add this to your Application class

```
FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.fromResource(this);
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, options);
```

This way you don't have to configure FirebaseOptions by hand.

Comment: This seems to work and is simpler than the other answer, thanks!

Comment: Getting error in manifest. 'authorities' attribute must be defined for <provider>

Comment: As @NishanthSreedhara mentioned, you will get an error with such description of provider. The right one should be with `authorities`, so it will look like this:

`<provider
   android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
   android:authorities="${applicationId}.firebaseinitprovider"
   android:enabled="false" />`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is caused by auto initialization process of Firebase. To solve this problem you should disable Firebase Init Provider and init Firebase manually. To do so, you should do the following:

Disable provider in your `AndroidManifest` file:

```
<provider
android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" 
android:authorities="${applicationId}.firebaseinitprovider" 
android:enabled="false" />
```

Initialize Firebase manually by adding such line to your `Application` class:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, FirebaseOptions.fromResource(this))
```

P.S. The answer of @ne'mi is almost correct except the fact that you need to add `authorities` to disable provider. Decided to create a new answer, it would be easier for others to find the fully functional answer.